# JSON e and JSON E

Tags: json, scientific-notation

On the JSON website [here](http://www.json.org/), it explains the different possibilities of JSON 'objects'.   However, in the numbers section, these appear:

`e`   |   `e+`  |  `e-`  |  `E` |  `E+` |  `E-`

1 - What do these represent?

In searching for an answer, `<E>` appears alot.

2 - Is `<E>` related to the above `e`|`E`s?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's the notation JSON (and most programming languages) use for scientific notation. Scientific notation is used to denote very large or small floating-point numbers. The `e` (or equivalently `E`) is equivalent to "×10^". For example,

`3.7e-5` = `3.7E-5` = 3.7×10<sup>-5</sup> = 0.000037

Positive or negative exponents may be used, and in the case of positive exponents, the `+` symbol may be omitted:

`6.02e+23` = `6.02e23` = 6.02×10<sup>23</sup> = 602 sextillion

More details are available at the [Wikipedia article on scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Answer (score -5):

The letter e looks a lot like the mathematical constant e (the 2.71828 thing) so languages usually let you use E instead. As shown by nandhp, it does the same thing as e.

Comment: The `e` or `E` used in scientific notation is not (directly) related to the mathematical constant `e`.

Comment: user3128163 was not suggesting that it is related to the constant.  They were referring to visually distinguishing it from the constant.