# Make value in JSON 1.0 instead of 1

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm creating a JSON string and I want to set `"scale"` to `1.0`. No matter what I do though, the output is always `"scale": 1` or if I'm using `toPrecision()` -> `"scale": "1.0"`.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var zoomLevel = {
       "zoom":getZoom__(sheet),
       "scale":getScale__(),    /* Want to receive "scale":1.0 here instead of 
                                   "scale":1 or "scale":"1.0" */
       "elements":rowsData
};

function getScale__() {
       var scale = 1.0;
       return scale;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON makes no difference between Integer and floating point : source wikipedia.

Now if have to use any such number then go with the scientific e notation as explained here:

[JSON e and JSON E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617818/json-e-and-json-e)

Comment: So if precision is absolutely important for you then go ahead with the e notation or drop it all together.